# Does changing ulimit get logged Mac/FreeBSD

Tags: osx, freebsd, logs, ulimit

For some reason our open files ulimit (-n) is getting changes to 256 when it should be 1024. I tried searching for limit in /var/log/{system.log,secure.log} but didn't see anything useful.  Any idea how to find out what changed the ulimit?  Mac OS X (essentially FreeBSD Unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not logged if it was done via a program or install script. To my knowledge it is only logged if it was done by elevating permissions.

Some common ways to set ulimit are in:

- /etc/sysctl.conf
- /etc/launchd.conf
- /etc/profile

These methods would not really create log entries though, and would only take effect on reboot (or re-log for /etc/profile)

Comment: I realized the problem was I didnt know ulimits were now managed by launchctl and was using the ulimit command instead of launchctl to change them which is not persistent or effective.

Comment: It's kind of a hierarchy. If sysctl is set to 500 then launchd can only go up to 500, and so on.